# Mongoose Virtuals : async setter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have this virtual :

```
userSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(function setPassword(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    this.encry_password = this.securePassword(password);
  })
  .get(function getPassword() {
    return this._password;
  });
```

Now my problem is that `this.securePassword(password);` is an async function.

```
  async securePassword(plainpassword) {
    if (!plainpassword) return '';
    try {
      return await argon2.hash(plainpassword);
    } catch (err) {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

Now if i do like this :

```
userSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(function setPassword(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    this.securePassword(password).then((value) => {
      this.encry_password = value;
    });
  })
  .get(function getPassword() {
    return this._password;
  });
```

Or like this :

```
userSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(async function setPassword(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    this.encry_password = await this.securePassword(password)
  })
  .get(function getPassword() {
    return this._password;
  });
```

What i get is this error :

```
"User validation failed: encry_password: Path `encry_password` is required."
```

Any solution on how can i solve this possibile with virtuals?

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5762

Comment: @eol Thanks , looks like they will never implement it :(